# Docker: Mern project page isn't loading

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to run a MERN project with Docker Toolbox since i'm on a Windows machine but my project doesn't run.
This is my project folder structure:

```
 ├───api
 │   └───Dockerfile
 ├───ui
 │   └───Dockerfile
 ├───docker-compose.yml
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   ui:
     build: ./ui
     ports:
       - '3000:3000'
     depends_on:
       - api
     #command: tail -f /dev/null
   api:
     build: ./api
     ports:
       - '8080:8080'
     depends_on:
       - mongo
   mongo:
     image: mongo
     ports:
       - '27017:27017'
```

`./ui/Dockerfile`

```
 FROM node:8
 # Create app directory
 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 # Install app dependencies
 COPY package*.json ./

 RUN npm install
 # Copy app source code
 COPY . .

 #Expose port and start application
 EXPOSE 3000
 CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`./api/Dockerfile`

```
 FROM node:8
 # Create app directory
 WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 # Install app dependencies
 COPY package*.json ./

 RUN npm install
 # Copy app source code
 COPY . .

 #Expose port and start application
 EXPOSE 8080
 CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` from my root everything seems to compile properly but it exits with `express-mongo-docker-tutorial_ui_1 exited with code 0`

```
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ui_1     |
 ui_1     | > ui@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
 ui_1     | > react-scripts start
 ui_1     |
 ui_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.27.0.4/
 ui_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
 ui_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
 ui_1     | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
 ui_1     | Starting the development server...
 ui_1     |
 express-mongo-docker-tutorial_ui_1 exited with code 0
```

`docker-machine ip default` prints out `192.168.99.101` so I go to `192.168.99.101:3000` but my page doesn't load

If I do `docker ps` I see

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
 fd90ffb3323f        express-mongo-docker-tutorial_api   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp     express-mongo-docker-tutorial_api_1
 5ed2d070b45f        mongo                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   express-mongo-docker-tutorial_mongo_1
```

I tried the solution of  adding `command: tail -f /dev/null` to my `docker-compose.yml` file and I do see the container

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
 a1d54f603fca        express-mongo-docker-tutorial_ui    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp     express-mongo-docker-tutorial_ui_1
 321682880d04        express-mongo-docker-tutorial_api   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago       Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp     express-mongo-docker-tutorial_api_1
 d8e31d09f8e5        mongo                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   express-mongo-docker-tutorial_mongo_1
```

but when I go to `192.168.99.101:3000` my page still doesn't load. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all I had to do was add `tty:true` in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
 ui:
  build: ./ui
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  depends_on:
    - api
  tty:true #<-----
```